# Best way to represent range of numbers in a set

Tags: python, class, set

I am trying to create a class which holds a bunch of integers. I am using `set` to do the same. But I would like to compress the memory footprint by storing continuous ranges in some other form, may  be a range object. But in such a case, how will I implement functionalities like `union`, `intersection`, `issubset` etc?

Below is my code as of now. In `__init__` I would like to implement a compress feature so that continuous ranges are not stored as is. Also, I would like to accept ranges as part of the items.

```
class Component(object):
    """
    Component class

    Attributes:
        name (str): The name of the component.
        type (str): The type of the component.
        items (set): The members of the component.
    """

    def __init__(self, comp_name, comp_type, comp_items):
        """
        Constructor for the Component object.

        Args:
            comp_name (str): Name of the component.
            comp_type (str): Type of the component.
            comp_items (iterable): An iterable of the members of the component.
        """
        self.name = comp_name
        self.type = comp_type.lower()
        if not all(isinstance(x, int) for x in comp_items):
            raise TypeError("All items in the component items should of type int")
        self.items = set(comp_items)

    @property
    def count(self):
        """Return the number of items in the component"""
        return len(self.items)

    def max(self):
        """Returns the max ID number from the component items"""
        return max(self.items)

    def min(self):
        """Returns the min ID number from the component items"""
        return min(self.items)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Representation of the component"""
        return "<Component Object-> Name:{}, Type:{}, Count: {}>".format(
            self.name, self.type, self.count
        )

    def __len__(self):
        """len() function on the Component object"""
        return len(self.items)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Checking if one component is equal to another"""
        return self.type == other.type and self.items == other.items

    def __and__(self, other):
        """Intersection of two components"""
        assert self.type == other.type
        return self.__class__("", self.type, self.items & other.items)

    def __or__(self, other):
        """Union of two components"""
        assert self.type == other.type
        return self.__class__("", self.type, self.items | other.items)

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Adding two components together"""
        return self.__or__(other)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """Removing one Component from another"""
        assert self.type == other.type
        return self.__class__("", self.type, self.items - other.items)

    def issubset(self, other):
        """Checking if self is a subset of other"""
        return self.items.issubset(other.items)

    def __contains__(self, other):
        return self.items.__contains__(other)
```

Comment: how about `range` as representation (if the integers are contiguous)?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, the set will have other numbers which are not in a range as well. So you're saying i'll represent everything as range? for eg: 1 would be `range(1,2)`?

Comment: if your ranges had been contiguous i would have suggested range, if that is not the case... i don't know... a list of ranges? hmmm...

Comment: If I do so, I may have quite a hard time implementing `issubset` and methods like that. I thought there would already be some design patterns which would do such a thing.